# Is there a multi-tab terminal replacement for Cygwin's terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, cygwin

Is there a multi-tab terminal replacement for Cygwin's terminal?

Comment: @DanielBeck this is not a duplicate *question*. It's a duplicate answer. Randomize is clearly looking for a multitab terminal for a *Unixy shell on Windows*---whereas the question you marked it as a duplicate of seems to be agnostic to shell type. Incidentally, both questions can be solved the same way. But I consider them two separate questions.

Comment: @Kazark Your edit made them duplicate, because Cygwin doesn't have its own terminal, but uses whatever you launch it in.

Comment: @DanielBeck But the questioner may not know that. I certainly did not; an item called "Cygwin Terminal" appears in the start menu after install. It has its own icon; are you say that it is the same terminal as the default on on Windows?

Comment: As of 2019 `mintty` supports tabs. You still have multiple mintty processes, tabs are just a permanent widget allowing navigation via click. `TabBar=yes`

Comment: fatty is what you need https://github.com/juho-p/fatty It's the good old cygwin + multi-tab, and nothing else.

Answer (score 32):

You can use [Console](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to achieve this. Simply configure the Shell under the Settings page to point to Cygwin.bat.

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works fine! just a question: in the Settings->Console under Startup Dir if I set the path dos-like (c:\path|...) or in *nix like (/cygdrive/c/... with or without /cygdrive) it doesn't come up at the specified path. Do you know how to set this? Thanks

Comment: I'm honestly not sure as it's been a while since I personally used Console. However if you can't find a way to set it properly in there, you could always edit your .bashrc file in your Cygwin installation to change to the desired folder upon login.

Comment: But if so every time I launch a new tab it will be CygWin. How can I use different tabs for different programs like what is in your snapshot?

Comment: I tried to use Console2 (last release dates 2011) to run Cygwin 64 bits in my Windows 7 64 bits and it didn't work. Researching a bit I was able to find [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) which is a fork of the former that is properly updated and was able to support the environment I described.

Comment: @Chuim - It *seems* to be working fine for me. Console 2.00.148 (32-bit according to Process Manager) running Cygwyn64 Terminal over Win 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 7):

The standard answer to this question is [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

[Wikipedia has some alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen#See_also), such as [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).

Comment: But unfortunately tmux doesn't work under cygwin

Comment: tmux is working great under cygwin for me at the moment, I just needed to select tmux in the list of installed packages.  That said, I still like having tabs in addition to split windows just like the OP.

Answer (score 5):

If it is not a problem for you to start sshd and use cygwin via "ssh localhost", try [MTPuTTY](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/). It worked great for me.

Features:

- full access to PuTTY configurability (and I do not know any better terminal emulator for windows)
- configurable keybindings in MTPuTTY (everything I needed)

Answer (score 3):

[mobaxterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) might be what you're looking for - basic set of cywin tools (and you can use your own) multi tabs, and an x server baked right in